# Could anybody please point me to an example of implementing an option's contract using Corda?

Tags: corda

I couldn't find such an example for "option" contract in Corda.

Could anybody please point me to such an example?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help you familiarize yourself with SO's process, I would recommend that you take the [tour] and read [ask]. Upon completion, you should [edit] your question and provide us with a [mcve] to help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

A set of sample CorDapps is provided here: https://www.corda.net/samples/.

One of these samples is an options CorDapp. See https://github.com/caisr3/cordapp-optionv1.